# Search by multiple fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
   {_id: ..., fullname: 'fullname', username: 'username'},
   {_id: ..., fullname: 'fullname2', username: 'username2'},
```

and I have a searchfield to search both `fullname` and `username` and get the results.

The problem is my implementation is not working.

```
users = await User.find({
    $or: [
      {
        fullname: { $regex: search, $options: "i" },
        username: { $regex: search, $options: "i" },
      },
    ],
  })
```

where search is the value of search input.

How Can I solve this ?

Comment: From a quick glance things look fine, you should be more specific about the issue's you're having.

Answer (score 1):

From the MongoDB documentation for [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

> The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions.

Your example has an array with a single element:

```
{
    fullname: { $regex: search, $options: "i" },
    username: { $regex: search, $options: "i" },
}
```

Meaning it will return documents where both `fullname` and `username` match against the pattern passed in `search`.

Because you used `$or`, I think you intended something like this:

```
users = await User.find({
    $or: [
      {
        fullname: { $regex: search, $options: "i" },
      },
      {
        username: { $regex: search, $options: "i" },
      }
    ],
  })
```

Note that this passes `$or` two different expressions, one where `fullname` needs to match the regex, and a second one where `username` needs to match the regex.